# I want to display both at the same time in woocomerce products sorting, sort by name (asc) and sort by name (des). I have use this code

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Below code display the sorting by name in DECS order, but if I'm same copy and write `$sorts_args['order']   = 'acs';`  display in ascending order but after his decs in not showing, I want to display both sorts by name (asc) and sort by name (desc) at the same time. wherever the user clicks display according to its query. What can I do to display both at the same time? Thank You, seniors.

```
function save_ordering_args( $sorts_args ) {

$orderby_value2 = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( 
$_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 
get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

switch( $orderby_value2 ) {

  // Name your sortby key whatever you'd like; must correspond to the $sortby 
  in the next function

case 'slug':

   $sorts_args['orderby'] = 'menu_order title';

   // Sort by ASC because we're using alphabetic sorting

   $sorts_args['order']   = 'desc';


 break;        
}

return $sorts_args;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'save_ordering_args' );

// Add these new sorting arguments to the sortby options on the frontend

function save_add_new_orderby( $sortsby ) {



// Adjust the text as desired

$sortsby['slug'] = __( 'Sort by name (desc)', 'woocommerce' );



return $sortsby;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 
'save_add_new_orderby' );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'save_add_new_orderby' );


/**
* Rename product data tabs
*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'save_rename_tabs', 98 );
function save_rename_tabs( $tabbs ) {
$tabbs['additional_information']['title'] = __( 'Accessorie' ); // Rename 
the additional information tab

return $tabbs;
}

/** 
* Change on single product panel "Additional Information"
*/
 add_filter('woocommerce_product_additional_information_heading',
 'save_product_additional_information_heading');

 function save_product_additional_information_heading() {
 echo '<h2>Accessorie</h2>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin Name: More Sorting Options for WooCommerce

Use Above Plugin to display both at same time, Sorts by name/title (A to Z / Ascending) and Sort by name/title (A to Z / Descending).

After this go to Woocommerce --> Setting --> Sorting Option --> Custom Sorting--> Here you can change according to your need. Thanks